# app terminates after launched in ios device in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to debug my xamarin application in ios device.but after lunch successfully it terminates and debugger gets detached.

Message in output window is  :

**Launching 'FormBot.iOS' on 'Testsoft's iPhone'...
The app has been terminated.**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">

    <dict>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Fonts/proximanovalight.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>GreenBot</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.tatvasoft.allxamarin</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>Icon-72@2x.png</string>
        <string>Icon-72.png</string>
        <string>Icon@2x.png</string>
        <string>Icon.png</string>
        <string>Icon-60@2x.png</string>
        <string>Icon-76.png</string>
        <string>Icon-76@2x.png</string>
        <string>Default.png</string>
        <string>Default@2x.png</string>
        <string>Default-568h@2x.png</string>
        <string>Default-Landscape.png</string>
        <string>Default-Landscape@2x.png</string>
        <string>Default-Portrait.png</string>
        <string>Default-Portrait@2x.png</string>
        <string>Icon-Small-50@2x.png</string>
        <string>Icon-Small-50.png</string>
        <string>Icon-Small-40.png</string>
        <string>Icon-Small-40@2x.png</string>
        <string>Icon-Small.png</string>
        <string>Icon-Small@2x.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.3</string>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <string>YES</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to the camera to take photos.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to photos.</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your app do? Can you show some code? Stack trace doesn't show anything?

Comment: app is working fine in simulator ,android device as well.so there is no issue in code.and it is whole project so which part of code should i share?

Comment: That sounds like a permission issue with the iOS 10 permission requirements. Does your app use the Camera, Location, Photos or anything that requires user permission?

Comment: yes. it requires.but i provided that also in info.plist

Comment: Could you update your post with a printscreen of you info.plist file and also tell what operations is your app trying to do? Just to confirm you didn't miss anything

Comment: i updates post with info.plist

Comment: Does the app works if launched from the phone and not from the debugger?

Comment: yes.it launches succesfully.but i get detached from debugger saying app terminated.after that i can run that launched app from phone sure

Comment: but i want to debug it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unexpected but this helped me. in xamarin there are so many tricks which helps us solving some weird error without any logic.

in this case I manually opened app by clicking on app icon generated at build time start running app and will hit breakpoints too.

I think the visual studio successfully deploys app here but having problem in open it .so as it lunch if we manually open app .it runs perfect..

this might help some one else.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This could be a few things. First and foremost, Build -> Clean All -> Restart Xamarin Studio (or VS).

If that doesn't do it, it's possibly a provisioning profile issue. Make sure you're building with a development profile.

Comment: Yes, i was working with a new iPad, and for me it was probably restarting VS Mac and XCode, and Clean All, then build again. You can delete the bin and obj folders in your app folder, too. Maybe it was also trusting the device in XCode. (the trust computer dialogue on iOS also sometimes takes about 15 minutes to show up on a new device)